# Sonata + Fos_user - How to display only entities related to the user?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata

I have users who are venue managers. I want them to be able to manage their places and events that are happening in these places.

I created fos_user_user and there I built relations to places:

```
<entity name="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="fos_user_user">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="integer">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>
    <many-to-many field="places" target-entity="EchoBundle\Entity\Place">
        <join-table name="users_places">
            <join-columns>
                <join-column name="user_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
            </join-columns>
            <inverse-join-columns>
                <join-column name="place_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
            </inverse-join-columns>
        </join-table>
    </many-to-many>
</entity>
```

So now, I can manage users and add places that they manage. It works fine.

Questions:

1. How can I filter so once they log in they only see their own places?
2. How can I allow them to only add events to their own places? Currently when you add an event you have a full list of places to select from.
3. How can I filter all events so that they only see events related to places they manage?

I looked at "CUSTOMIZING THE QUERY USED TO GENERATE THE LIST" in the Sonata documentation but don't know how to use it. I tried to add security queries found in answers on StackOverflow from 4 years ago but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Admin class you can override `createQuery` (you should check and fix example below to meet your app model) ;)
This solution will cover question 1 and 3.

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    $aliases = $query->getRootAliases();
    $query
        ->leftJoin($aliases[0] . '.users_places', 'users_places')
        ->andWhere($query->expr()->eq('users_places.user_id', ':user') )
        ->setParameter('user', $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser());

    return $query;
}
```

Question 2:
If you are using sonata `formMapper` and `configureFormFields` method, you can pass Custom Query Builder in field definition.

```
$formMapper
    ->add('events', 'sonata_type_model', [
        'label' => 'Events',
        'placeholder' => 'Select ...',
        'required' => true,
        'query' => $blQueryBuilder,
    ]);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am almost there.
Regarding the second one, I have something like that in the add event form:
->add('place', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                    'class' => 'EchoBundle:Place',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'label' => 'Place',
                    'query' => $placeQuery,
                ))'

But I have a problem to build query that list places only belonging to the user. In the "raw" SQL it would be:
SELECT DISTINCT p.name FROM users_places u LEFT JOIN places p ON u.places_id=p.id...

Comment: Regarding the first - I added it but received:
Attempted to call an undefined method named "andWhere" of class "Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Comparison".

Comment: Hi,
I'm sorry I have made a mistake in answer. 
Query expr builder `$query->expr()->eq` should be moved to from select to andWhere clause.

Comment: So form element query should look similar to this:
`$qb = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('doctrine')
->getRepository('ApplicationSonataUserBundle:UserPlaces')->createQueryBuilder('up');
$placesQuery = $qb
    ->select('DISTINCT up.name')
    ->leftJoin('up.places', 'places')
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('up.user', ':user'))
    ->setParameter('user', $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser())
    ->getQuery();`

Comment: almost there but...
'You have requested a non-existent service "doctrine‌​".'

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is impossible inside Admin Class. Can you share some code than?